# Salesforce seem did not sync back to Heroku Postgres

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

Currently, I develop a Heroku app that using Heroku Connect for sync data to Salesforce system.
Normally, when my data insert to Database(Heroku Postgresql) successfully, data will synced to Salesforce system. And after that, Salesforce will push realated Salesforce data(ex: sfId, system fields, compound field...) synced back to Heroku Postgres.(_hc_lastop = 'SYNC')
But recently, Salesforce seem did not push the related data synced back to Heroku Postgres automatically.(_hc_lastop = 'INSERTED'). Only sfId is populated.

Very strange. Have you ever stuck in this situation?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out the issue and resolve it?

Comment: @Jbrack No, that's be solved automatically for a while. I think there is an issue of Heroku Connect.

Comment: Thanks for following up, I'll contact Heroku to see if this issue is still affecting me, thanks!